# Meaning of combined $L^p$ and Sobolev spaces in fluid dynamics

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics

I have a problem [here](http://62.182.86.140/main/1504000/b99b4bce369f4b53fe8a5cedf4c58106/Lemarie-Rieusset%2C%20Pierre%20Gilles%20-%20The%20Navier-Stokes%20Problem%20in%20the%2021st%20Century-CRC%20Press%20%282016%29.pdf) with the definition on the page 372 of $$L^2((0,+\infty),L^2).$$
What functions form this space? I do not also understand this spaces:

$$L^p L^q$$ and

$$L^2 \dot{H}^1.$$

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This notation is slightly compacted to make it easier to read, but it can be confusing for the uninitiated. A spatial domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed and we can construct the standard function spaces on $\Omega$; e.g., $L^q(\Omega)$, $H^1(\Omega)$, $\dot{H}_1(\Omega)$, etc. You should be familiar with these. Notice that elements of these sets can be considered functions of $x$, the spatial variable and the different spaces impose different amounts of regularity on these functions and their derivatives.

However, if we wish to construct weak solutions to the Navier-Stokes equations, we need some measure of the regularity with respect to time as well. A simple case looks something like $u\in C^1([0,T],X)$, where $X$ is some Banach space. This statements means that the mapping $t\mapsto u(t)$, $t\in[0,T]$ is $C^1$ with respect to the topology on $X$. In the same way we typically extend spaces of continuous functions to $L^p$ spaces, we can extend this definition to include measureable maps from $[0,T]$ (or any other interval of time) from $[0,T]$ to $X$ with some degree of regularity.

For a concrete example, consider the space in the first bullet point: $u\in L^\infty((0,T),L^2)\cap L^2((0,T),H^1).$ This can be read as follows:

> $u$ is a map from $(0,T)\to X\subset L^2(\Omega)\cap H^1(\Omega)$ such that the map
> $t\mapsto u(t)$ is essentially bounded with respect to the topology on $L^2(\Omega)$ and is square-integrable on $(0,T)$ with respect to the topology on $H_1(\Omega)$.

In concrete terms, these last two conditions read

> $$\left\|~\|u(t)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}~\right\|_{L^\infty(0,T)} = \sup_{s\in(0,T)}\|u(s)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\text{ is finite.}$$

and

> $$\left\|~\|u(t)\|_{H^1(\Omega)}~\right\|_{L^2(0,T)}=\left(\int_0^T\|u(s)\|_{H^1}^2~\mathrm{d}s\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\text{ is finite.}$$

With this in mind, we can now read off the shorthand notation. The time interval is hard to determine from the context, but it appears to be the case that $$L^pL^q=L^p([0,T],L^q(\Omega)),\quad\text{and}\quad L^2H^1 = L^2([0,T],H^1(\Omega)).$$
This condensed notation $u\in XY$ for two functions spaces $X$ and $Y$ tends to mean  that $u$ is a $X$-regular mapping from the real line to $Y$, representing the time dependence, and $Y$ represents the spatial regularity of the elements $u(t)$.

Note: I have abused notation a bit in my definition of spaces on $\Omega$, since the functions here should be vector-valued. If one wished to be very clear, one should write, for example, $L^2(\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n)$ and one must use the appropriate norms.

Comment: Great. By the same token, on the page 389, I do not follow the definitions of $$\operatorname{div}(\overrightarrow{u}\otimes \overrightarrow{u})$$ and, in particular  $$\overrightarrow{u}\otimes \overrightarrow{u}$$ Perhaps you could edit your answer or reply in a comment so that I do not need create new Q. ?

Comment: Anyway what is $H^1$ ?

Comment: Your link is broken, but $u\otimes u$ is a tensor product: $u\otimes u = T$ with elements $T_{ij} = u_iu_j$. The divergence operator is an operator on tensors that reduces the rank of a tensor in the following way $\mathrm{div}(T)_k = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} T_{ik}$. For this example, $\mathrm{div}(u\otimes u)_k = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u_k$.

Comment: If you do not know the definitions of Sobolev spaces, then you should take the time to review more fundamental concepts before delving into weak solutions of Navier-Stokes equations. *Partial Differential Equations* by Lawrence C. Evans is a good reference. Terence Tao's notes may also be helpful, but I would recommend reading them along with Evans: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/254a-notes-1-local-well-posedness-of-the-navier-stokes-equations/ https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/10/02/254a-notes-2-weak-solutions-of-the-navier-stokes-equations/

Comment: Please, try to copy and paste it into your browser's tab directly. It cannot be clicked immediately but copy and paste should download that book.

Comment: Most would prefer not to download something unprompted from clicking a link, Regardless, I believe I have answered your question.

Comment: Sorry what is meant by `unprompted` ? I'm not a native English speaker. .... Yes, you have answered it, thank you for your patience and clarity.

Comment: I mean that when you click the link, it downloads the book without asking or showing you what the file is before it downloads.

Comment: Is this $\otimes$ somehow related to a tensor product in modules ${}_R\mathbf{Mod}$ as a quotient by relations$M\times N/R$ ? How can I see a relationship of the two definitions ?

Comment: It is some feature of the pdfs from that site. It really doesn't start immediately downloading by some reason.