# Definition of spatial and temporal function spaces in Brezis

Tags: functional-analysis, heat-equation

There are two points which are not clear for me in Brezis's book *Functional Analysis*: The space  $L^2 (0, \infty; H^1_0(\Omega))$, what is its definition?

I found in Evans book the  definition of space $L^2 (0, T; H^1_0(\Omega))$ : it is  the space of measurable functions u such that
$$ \int_0^\infty \left\Vert u(t) \right\Vert ^2 _{H^1_0(\Omega)} 
~\mathrm{d}t < \infty.$$  Can I just put $T=\infty$ to get defintion of $L^2 (0, \infty; H^1_0(\Omega))$?

What about this space: $C((0,\infty,L^{p}(\Omega))$? How can one  define it? For $T$ finite and  for $C((0,T,L^{p}(\Omega))$ it is space of strongly continious function such that:
$$\|u(t)-u(s)\|_{L^{p}}\to 0 \ as t \to s,$$
but I dont think it will be true for $T=\infty$.

My second question  for $T$ finite we have that $C((0,T,L^{p}(\Omega))$ is a Banach space, but For $T =\infty$ this is false?
Please if you have any references where I can find the definition of these spaces it will be great help.
Thank you.

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763036/meaning-of-combined-lp-and-sobolev-spaces-in-fluid-dynamics/4763053#4763053

Comment: I cleaned up your text a bit and removed where you defined $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$ twice. Please check to ensure that this is accurate.

Comment: @whpowell96 but it is just fot T finite and me i cant see how to definie these spaces if T is $\infty$ so please if you have idea i will be grateful